# System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException Issue

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, unit-testing

I have a test method that tests a task that is suppose to get a task definition (task description) for edit:

```
[TestMethod]
public void GetTaskDefinitionsForEdit_HavingTaskDefinitions_ReturnsChecklistTaskDefinitions()
{
    // this.CreateChecklistTaskDefinition(referenceKey: "Xxx123", description: "SomeDescription");
    // this.checklistTaskTestHelper.CreateChecklistTaskDefinition(referenceKey: "Yyy234", description: "SomeOtherDescription");

    this.helper.CreateChecklistTaskDefinition(referenceKey: "Xxx123", description: "SomeDescription");
    this.helper.CreateChecklistTaskDefinition(referenceKey: "Yyy234", description: "SomeOtherDescription");

    this.CompanyDbContext.SaveChanges();

    //var result = this.checklistTaskTestHelper.checklistTaskDefinitionRepository.GetTaskDefinitionsForEdit(ChecklistReferenceType.ReconAccountGroup, "Xxx123");

    var result = this.checklistTaskDefinitionRepository.GetTaskDefinitionsForEdit(ChecklistReferenceType.ReconAccountGroup, "Xxx123");

    Assert.AreEqual(1, result.Count);
    //Assert.AreEqual("Xxx123", result[0].ReferenceKey);
    //Assert.AreEqual("SomeDescription", result[0].Description);
}
```

I also have an initilize method:

```
protected override void Initialize()
{
    this.company = this.CreateCompany("Test company");
    this.checklistTaskDefinitionRepository = this.CreateRepository<ChecklistTaskDefinitionRepository>(this.company);
    this.helper = new ChecklistTaskTestHelper(this.checklistTaskDefinitionRepository, this.checklistTaskStatusRepository);
}
```

And these at the start of the class:

```
private Company company;
private ChecklistTaskDefinitionRepository checklistTaskDefinitionRepository;
private ChecklistTaskStatusRepository checklistTaskStatusRepository;
private ChecklistTaskTestHelper helper;
```

And as soon as I run the test method, It prints out this:

> Test method Core.Data.Test.Modules.Checklists.ChecklistTaskDefinitionRepositoryTest.GetTaskDefinitionsForEdit_HavingTaskDefinitions_ReturnsChecklistTaskDefinitions threw exception: 
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries.

Comment: ambient DbContext variables are highly error prone. What are the changes done previously, which objects are in the ChangeTracker, what do the two methods do and what is the inner exception?

Answer (score 0):

If you debug the test, you can retrieve the inner exception that in this case will give you the reason of the error (fk error, duplicated pk error, column does not exists, table does not exists, database does not exists).

To debug the test inside visual studio, right click on the test and click debug.

Comment: this is not an answer to the question, just an advice to debug. I'd believe this would be better as a comment